# Why does Apple Scrumdinger Sample App uses two sources of truth?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to figure out why apple instantiates DailyScrum.Data with @State in two different views. I thought you were only supposed to have one source of truth. I guess one is for creating new scrum data and the other is to provide updates or edit the scrum data. But I am not sure.

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var scrum: DailyScrum
    
    @State private var data = DailyScrum.Data()
    @State private var isPresentingEditView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Meeting Info")) {
                NavigationLink(destination: MeetingView(scrum: $scrum)) {
                    Label("Start Meeting", systemImage: "timer")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                }
               
            }
           
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScrumsView: View {
    @Binding var scrums: [DailyScrum]
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    @State private var isPresentingNewScrumView = false
    @State private var newScrumData = DailyScrum.Data()
    let saveAction: ()->Void
    
   var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach($scrums) { $scrum in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(scrum: $scrum)) {
                    CardView(scrum: scrum)
                }
                .listRowBackground(scrum.theme.mainColor)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Daily Scrums")
    }
}
```

[image: Scrumview to add a new scrum]

[image]

Comment: Please include code, not pictures of code, which can’t be copied/pasted, searched, or read by screen readers.

Comment: Changes are done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DailyScrum.Data()` is not really playing as the `source of truth` here.

If you focus closely, the `DailyScrum.Data()` was made as something similar to **a temp/helper variable**.

Say you have an edit view which users can edit the data. While the user input a new data, this new data will be stored inside the `DailyScrum.Data()` temporarily, so it will not affect your real `source of truth`.

This data will then be passed to your `source of truth` to be saved only if the users confirm to save.

Now you know why you need this `DailyScrum.Data()` because without it all your data will be changed immediately even before the users confirm to change.